Python to mySql workbench ((TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str))
I am doing some assignment for my class, and I have successfuly connected my python to mysql workbench
Show the connection is working
The screenshot shows the connection between python and sql, so is my code wrong?
Eventually, my AI needs to assist with weather conditions
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# Define the connection details
config = {
    'user': 'chatbot',  
    'password': 'PASSWORD1', 
    'host': 'hostname',  
    'database': 'MC_chatbot',  
    'port': 3306 
}

try:
    # Connect to the database
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    if connection.is_connected():
        print("Connected to the database successfully")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Function to fetch the weather response
        def get_weather_response():
            query = "SELECT response1, response2, response3, response4, response5, response6, response7, response8 FROM chat WHERE keyword = 'weather'"
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchone()  # Fetch the first row of the result
            if result:
                return [response for response in result if response]  # Return non-null responses
            else:
                return None

        # Function to handle user input and provide response
        def handle_user_input(user_input):
            if 'weather' in user_input.lower():
                responses = get_weather_response()
                if responses:
                    return responses[0]  # For simplicity, return the first response
                else:
                    return "Sorry, I don't have any information on the weather."
            else:
                return "I can only help with weather-related questions."

        # Example interaction
        user_input = input("You: ")
        response = handle_user_input(user_input)
        print("Bot:", response)

except Error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the connection
    if 'connection' in locals() and connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("Connection closed")

when i run the python script, i receive the folowing:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 728, in open_connection
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Capella\AI v2\Week 6\Assignment 6.py", line 13, in <module>
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 323, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1360, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 359, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 748, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u' (%s) (Warning: %u format: a real number is required, not str)

